# How to establish the connection with MongoDB using jMeter with JSR223 sampler?

Tags: mongodb, jmeter, performance-testing, jsr223

How to establish the connection with mongo dB using jmeter with JSR223 sampler? Whenever i am trying to establish connection it is failing without any response.I am suspecting this is due to auth mechanism.

Any help with necessary changes needs to be done on jmeter is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you face an issue with your script always check *jmeter.log* file, it should normally contain the root cause or at least enough information to guess it.

If you're looking for a built-in JMeter way of load testing MongoDB you will need to add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
not_in_menu
```

This way you will have [MongoDB Source Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Source_Config_(DEPRECATED)) back and will be able to specify your MongoDB host, port and other connection parameters. Later in JSR223 Sampler you will be able  to get db object like:

```
def db = MongoDBHolder.getDBFromSource('sourceName', 'databaseName')
```

or if you need to supply the credentials:

```
def db = MongoDBHolder.getDBFromSource('sourceName', 'databaseName', 'username', 'password')
```

More information: [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/ja/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it possible to use the "JDBC Connection" config to let Jmeter communicate with MongoDB?